# Writing apk file to android

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, webclient

I'm trying to write an apk file from a filestream to my android storage. I'm using Unity 3D with C#.
When testing on the PC I can send requests to my server (whichis also a c# console application), and save the apk file that my server sends me. It is a complete file and can be installed on any android.
However, when I build the project for android, it won;t wriet all the data to the storage device. here is the relevant code:

string apkFilePath = Application.persistentDataPath;

apkFilePath = apkFilePath + "/new.apk";

public void Receive()
    {

```
    byte[] RecData = new byte[BufferSize];
    int RecBytes;

    for (; ; )
    {

        string Status = string.Empty;
        try
        {

            int totalrecbytes = 0;
            if(File.Exists(apkFilePath))
            {
                File.Delete(apkFilePath);
            }
            FileStream Fs = new FileStream(apkFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
            while ((RecBytes = ns.Read(RecData, 0, RecData.Length)) > 0)
            {
                if (RecBytes >= BufferSize)
                {
                    print(RecBytes);
                    Fs.Write(RecData, 0, RecBytes);
                    totalrecbytes += RecBytes;
                    Fs.Flush();
                }
                if(RecBytes < BufferSize && RecBytes > 0)
                {
                    print(RecBytes);
                    Fs.Write(RecData, 0, RecBytes);
                    totalrecbytes += RecBytes;
                    Fs.Flush();
                    break;
                }

            }

            print("OUT OF LOOP");

            //Fs.Flush();
           Fs.Dispose();
                Fs.Close();


                    quit = true;

                    break;


        }


        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            //netstream.Close();
        }


    }







}
```

Any suggestions why it works for my PC but not on Android?

Comment: Most likely it has to do with the permissions that your application has, or doesn't have.

Comment: I've given it all the write permissions in the manifest. And it will write some of the data, just only a fraction of it.